# Associating image file document types with iPhone apps

Tags: iphone

I'm currently developing an app that needed to associate with different file types (PDF and all the image file types) so far I've managed to associate my app with PDF files but the problam is when i tried to do the same with image files it just doesn't work.

is it even possible to associate PNG, JPG etc to you app ?

If it is, am i doing it right ? (the same way i took care of the pdf through the app plist "CFBundleDocumentTypes" )

I'll really appriciate any kind of help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, try adding this to your application. Make sure you have an Icon named DocumentIcon.png that is 22 px by 29 px.

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>DocumentIcon.png</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>My App Name</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>org.gnu.gnu-zip-archive</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

This will work for opening files of type .gz. However, if you change the LSItemContentTypes to public.image or public.jpeg, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue... I believe this doesn't work because applications like Mail on the iPhone display images as images and not attachments...I have noticed that if I change my setup to use any other file type this does work.